# initialize then increment the rownumber of a record set if

Tags: php, mysql, select

I'm trying to use one `mysql select query` to count and increment a variable/non existing column only if `orders_status` not equal to `pulled` or `pulling` or else it's `empty`. I intend on using the count in a php script that executes a flag if `row_number=400`

```
$orders_query_raw = "SELECT
                    o.orders_id,
                    o.customers_name,
                    o.payment_method,
                    o.date_purchased,
                    o.delivery_date,
                    o.delivery_time_slotid,
                    o.last_modified,
                    o.currency,
                    o.currency_value,
                    s.orders_status_name,
                    ot.text as order_total
                FROM " . TABLE_ORDERS . " o
                LEFT JOIN " . TABLE_ORDERS_TOTAL . " ot ON (o.orders_id = ot.orders_id), " . TABLE_ORDERS_STATUS . " s
                WHERE o.orders_status = s.orders_status_id
                  AND s.language_id = '" . (int)$languages_id . "'
                  AND s.orders_status_id = '" . (int)$status . "'
                  AND ot.class = 'ot_total'
                ORDER BY o.orders_id DESC";
```

**Initial result:**

```
orders_id | orders_status 
     34a  |  pulling          
     45a  |  pending      
     45u  |  pulled       
     36c  |  payment_due
```

**Desired result returned**

```
orders_id | orders_status | rownumber
     34a  |  pulling      |   
     45a  |  pending      |   1
     45u  |  pulled       |   
     36c  |  payment_due  |   2
```

Comment: Can you give us the code you are working on?

Comment: why do you need that index? from SQL side it has no sense, which row must be 1st, and which one 2nd? is there any rule? if all rows have same priority, how can SQL set that number? what do you plan to do if `row_number==400` ???

Comment: It's the initial query, there's a splitoageresults function that is complicating thing. Figure if I can just add a temporary column I can utilize the column variable later on.

Answer (score 1):

You can increment the value as you want using variables.  Your query is a bit complicated, but here is the idea:

```
select . . .,
       (case when order_status in ('pulled', 'pulling') then NULL
             else @rn := @rn + 1
        end) as rownumber
from . . . cross join
     (select @rn := 0) vars;
```

Comment: WOW, cool, I should remember this. Do you know is it really works fast? in real situation is it more efficient than to just select and counting on php side?

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for... because of my splitpage function i had to implement Logans approach

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this code. Just replace the necessary `table` name, `column` name, and `variables`:

```
$result = mysqli_query($YourDBconnection,"SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE orders_status<>'pulling' AND orders_status<>'pulled' ORDER BY orders_id");

$count = 1; /* SET A COUNTER */

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

  $orderid = $row["orders_id"];
  mysqli_query($YourDBconnection,"UPDATE yourTable SET rownumber='$count' WHERE orders_id='$orderid'"); /* UPDATE THE TABLE */

  $count=$count+1; /* INCREMENT YOUR COUNTER */

}
```

Comment: Although Gordons recommendation was exactly what i was looking for. In my case, I had to go with yours Logan. I was trying to avoid adding a new column to the database but less code = more production.

Comment: @Eric - if my answer did help you, you can still upvote my answer, or if it really solves your whole problem, you can mark it as the right answer.

Comment: Logan, I would but appearently i dont have enough reputation points to upvote it. Thank you for your time though, I'm a stickler about giving credit where credit is due and unfortunatley ill loose some sleep tonight over this one. ;)